# GcmExample.xcodeproj sample app not found in pod

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I'm following this official guide for [Google Cloud Messaging for iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start) :

> Start with the sample using the following command from a terminal:
>
> > pod try Google
>
> Select the option for GcmExample.xcodeproj from the prompt.

But here's my console output:

```
pod try Google

Updating spec repositories

Trying Google
1: Samples/analytics/AnalyticsExample.xcodeproj
2: Samples/signin/SignInExample.xcodeproj
Which project would you like to open
```

There is no option for GcmExample at all.

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't find this directory,
My solution is
fire up your terminal and hit ->

```
->cd yourCloningDirectory
->git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git
```

then after cloning or downloading

```
->cd google-services(downloaded directory)->ios->gcm->
```

Here is your **GCMExample.xcodeproj**.

```
->pod install
```

(if failed to install/not found repo,try updating the Podfile like

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'Google/CloudMessaging' )

```
->open GCMExample.xcworkspace
```

Here is your working demo project.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). New code should use `Firebase` pod and not the `Google` pod. For the FCM sample, you can do

```
pod try Firebase
```

and select `Samples/messaging/FCM.xcodeproj` from the list

Comment: GCM has not been deprecated, it will still work as it previously did. However it is not in the list of Google try projects. You should give FCM a try via pod try Firebase.

Comment: I already have GCM implemented on the backend and on the Android app. I am fully vested in GCM. I cannot afford to switch to Firebase. To Google: you released GCM in 2012, please don't deprecated it so soon and screw me like this.

Comment: @Myothercarisacadr: The APIs of FCM and GCM are pretty analogous and it should be very easy to change. Alternately, you can look at the [podspec for Google 2.0.4](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Google/2.0.4/Google.podspec.json) (the previous version before the removed all of the services), manually download the package from the URL in there, and then look at the Samples directory in that.